# getting access to iframe website

Tags: java, javascript, iframe

Hey I am looking for some solution, i want to make it possible to have a iframe with a page from a different domain. and gain the xpath of the element which the user selects. it should work on all public web pages.

To use a java browser or Flash Browser isn't the purpose.

Greetings and thanks for your answers.

Comment: The short answer is "not possible". You need some server side logic to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can display an web page from another domain using an iframe like so.

```
<iframe src="http://www.weather.com" width="100%" height="300">
   <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

However, if you're saying that you want to be able to capture an element selectd on the page that is being displayed in the iframe then that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called [Cross-Site Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), and its not possible in [modern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) browsers anymore, unless you find an unpatched hole ;)

Comment: I know what Xss is but ... I still want to have read access to the DOM of the targeted site. ;-) but anyway i guess i have to look into server side logics then.